# Passport expired while outside the US

Tags: passports, us-citizens, paperwork, minors

My passport expired in early May of this year. My mother and I have lived down in Baja for about four years now so she can write her books. We make trips up to the states but not so many. I actively check my passport expiration date. I got it issued May 2009, and I was 11 at the time. Now I'm 17. Do I require a birth certificate or just my old passport to get it renewed at the consulate?

Comment: http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/16-and-17.html

Comment: Thank you but I read that already, I need to know if using my expired passport as identification is a valid method for applying in another country.

Comment: This might be better on the [Expats.SE site](http://expats.stackexchange.com/), since it relates to living abroad for some time then trying to apply for official documents whilst abroad

Comment: Chasing through the pages, they do say that the proof of citizenship list is the same (that is, you can use your expired passport) but to check with the embassy that you plan to use. Here's [Tijuana's](http://tijuana.usconsulate.gov/tijuana/passports/minor-passport-applicants.html).

Comment: Thank you mkennedy, I have found other sources saying I cannot use it because I am a minor still so I am going to contact the embassy directly and double check.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Per http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/renew.html:

From Outside the United States:

- U.S. citizens residing abroad (except those living in Canada) should renew their passports at the nearest U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate.  For more information on Applying for a U.S. passport from outside the United States, please click here.
- U.S. citizens residing in Canada may submit Form DS-82: Application for U.S. Passport by Mail to the address listed on the form.
- Passports renewed by mail in the United States may only be mailed to United States and Canadian addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to bring your birth certificate to the consulate.

Also, check the [regulations](http://mexico.usembassy.gov/eng/eacs_passports_general.html) specific to Mexico. For me, the required process was:

1. Mail the passport, original birth certificate, and application form to the embassy using a specific courier.

   - No flexibility on this. The embassy was serving many walk-ins by sending them to a counter inside the embassy, where they had the privilege of mailing the materials to the same embassy. The courier was the same and, I assume, the fees.
2. Wait for e-mail confirmation of the application.
3. Go to the embassy in person. Solemnly swear that you are whom you claim to be.
4. They mail your old passport and application to Washington. It gets mailed back together with the new one.
5. The new passport is mailed to you using the same courier.

Sounds pretty straightforward, but can be a slow process. Getting to step 2 took a month for my friend. In between steps 3 and 4, they lost my application and passport, but did not tell me so. After a month, I got suspicious and visited again, which is an all-day trip. After an hour of investigation, they found my materials inside a desk drawer. They did not even apologize. In the meantime my visa expired and I accrued penalties. Be ready for a little aggravation.